# Rails 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 not working no matter what vehicle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, osx-lion

I have installed rails on a previous mac that was running lion with all of the same internals as the computer I am trying to install it on. No matter what way i try to get rails on my comp via RVM it gives me a prompt saying i need to install libksba so I tried that via mac ports and when I tried that mac ports said i should delete xcode if i use the port command.

The commands i tried are as follows:

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
 port install libksba 
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

The last command is where i get error messages. If someone knows a sure fire way to get rails i would be eternally greatfull!

EDIT**** i ended up installing homebrew and uninstalling macports and installed libksba through that how ever when i go back and try to install 1.9.3 through rvm it gives me this message.

```
Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below. Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.
Notes for Mac OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.5.2.
For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26" For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6                                                                 For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba' For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/ To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
rvm alias create default 1.8.7 And reopen your terminal windows. Xcode and gcc::
```

Comment: Some more information about the errors would be helpful.

Comment: how about you use https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv since you are not yet using rvm.  rbenv is much simpler.

Comment: I added an update, i ended up using homebrew. Thanks for your time btw :)

Comment: I see you latest update, and you're trying to install ruby through RVM which is giving you the standard "todo" list - what problem are you having now?

Comment: It will just stop there. Lik it says on the last line and reopen your terminal widows. Xcode and gcc::. Im pretty sure it isnt installing becase when i try and make 1.9.3 default it says i need to install it. Thanks for your help btw

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [RVM documentation for Mac OS X](https://rvm.io/os/osx/) it's clear that you should be compiling Ruby 1.9.3 with `gcc` rather than `clang`. Unfortunately the Ruby compatible version of `gcc` is not installed with current versions of Xcode.

The best instructions I've found for installing the old `gcc` are in this post [Xcode, Homebrew and Ruby](http://jfire.io/blog/2012/03/02/xcode-4-dot-3-homebrew-and-ruby/).

Note that the instructions in the post say to use `clang` for `1.9.3` but you should instead use `gcc` with the command

```
ruby install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2
```

You may also see a note from rvm that `autoreconf` is required. I this case you can install `automake` with `homebrew` and the necessary files will be installed.

Comment: thank you! but everything works until i get to the installation of 1.9.3 I followed all the instructions in that article

Comment: its still saying i need to install the libksba etc same thing it seems like rvm doesnt like my computer. I also upgraded to mountain lion to see if that would help and it didnt :/